# Insert values into temp Table with Partition By

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, sql-insert, row-number

If have a temporary table declared as following:

```
CREATE TABLE #tempKleerkast(
id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
IDKleerkastPersoon int,
ID_Persoon int,
rk int
)
```

Now i wish to fill up the table with the values from an actual table where i want to get the **latest** (Not Max) record for each person. Therefor i'm using the following query:

```
      SELECT 
      DISTINCT IDKleerkastPersoon AS Expr1, kk.ID_Persoon,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY kk.ID_Persoon
                            ORDER BY kk.IDKleerkastPersoon DESC) AS rk
      FROM KleerkastPerPersoon kk
      WHERE  kk.ID_Persoon IS NOT NULL AND rk = 1
```

The problem is where is when i wish to use **insert into** as following:

```
      INSERT INTO #tempKleerkast(IDKleerkastPersoon,ID_Persoon,rk)
      SELECT 
      DISTINCT IDKleerkastPersoon AS Expr1, kk.ID_Persoon,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY kk.ID_Persoon
                            ORDER BY kk.IDKleerkastPersoon DESC) AS rk
      FROM KleerkastPerPersoon kk
      WHERE  kk.ID_Persoon IS NOT NULL AND rk = 1
```

I get the following error: **Invalid column name 'rk'.**
Any idea why he doesn't recognise the column rk?

**Note:** The column rk is needed further on in the stored procedure. So i can't exclude it.

Comment: the question is about my sql-statement (syntax). Not about working with sql-server (the product). Hence the tag sql instead of sql-server

Comment: But then you should add a tag for whatever **other** concrete database you're using; many things aren't defined in the SQL standard, but they differ from vendor to vendor.... (e.g. not **all** database vendors and systems support the `OVER(PARTITION BY...)` construct...)

Comment: Modified the tags! It should now contain the sql-servertag. I'll keep it in mind to specify it more clearly in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the problem comes before you write the `INSERT`. Try running just the plain `SELECT` and you'll see exactly the same error. [Logically](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx), `WHERE` runs before `SELECT` so you can't refer to aliases introduced by the latter in the former.

This should work:

```
  INSERT INTO #tempKleerkast(IDKleerkastPersoon,ID_Persoon,rk)
  SELECT IDKleerkastPersoon, ID_Persoon, rk
  FROM (
     SELECT
       IDKleerkastPersoon, kk.ID_Persoon,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY kk.ID_Persoon
                        ORDER BY kk.IDKleerkastPersoon DESC) AS rk
     FROM KleerkastPerPersoon kk
     WHERE  kk.ID_Persoon IS NOT NULL) t
  WHERE rk = 1
```

(I also removed the `DISTINCT` since one of the columns listed was also a column listed in the `PARTITION BY` clause and we're only selecting one row from each partition)

Comment: Your solution worked like a charm! I suppose is should use the same logic (for inserting into temptables) for any other aggregates (AVG,SUM,MAX,...) in the future?